# Trying to find a continuous bijection

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am doing problem 34 of chapter 1 in Stein & Shakarchi's Real Analysis text book and I am having a bit of trouble. The question goes as follows "Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be any two cantor sets. Show that there exists a function F : [0,1]$\rightarrow$[0,1] with the following properties:
(i) F is continuous and bijective,
(ii) F is monotonically increasing,
(iii) F maps $C_1$ surjectively onto $C_2$."
Now I can easily construct a continuous function f : C$_1$$\rightarrow$[0,1] by using a variation of the Cantor-Lebesgue function and hence extend this function f to [0,1] by making it on constant on the subintervals which are not in C$_1$. This function f will be continuous, monotonically increasing and it's restriction to C$_1$ will map C$_1$ surjectively onto C$_2$ because the restriction already maps C$_1$ surjectively onto [0,1]. The only problem here is that my function is not bijective. So I was wondering if anybody could construct a function which satisfies all of the requirements. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Recall the construction of Cantor sets. So you have sequences $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ of compact sets with $C_1 = \bigcap A_n$ and $C_2 = \bigcap B_n$. Can you, for fixed $n$ find a continuous monotonic bijection of $[0,1]$ that maps $A_n$ to $B_n$?